# what is wrong in this simple exercise? Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently learning NodeJS and I'm doing some basics exercises with the core modules.My file structure goes like this:

```
exercise-10/
           /static 
                 |index.html
                 |page1.html
                 |page2.html 
           /index.js
```

Here is my code:

```
var http=require('http');
var url=require('url');
var fs=require('fs');

  const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{

try{

   var objUrl = url.parse(req.url)

   var path = 'static' + objUrl.pathname

   if(path === 'static/') path = 'static/index.html';

  //DEBBUGIN
   console.log( path ) //logs "static/index.html"

   if(fs.existsSync(path)){

       fs.readFile(path, (error, data) => {
           if(error){

               res.writeHead(500,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'})
               res.write('Something went wrong! ')
               return res.end();
           }else{
               res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
               res.write(data)
               return res.end();
           }
        })

      }else{  // <-- logs this else statement
          res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
          res.write('<!doctype html><html><head></head><body> Something went wrong!  fs.existsSync = false </body></html>');        
          return res.end();
    }

  }catch(err){
     console.error(err)
  }
  })

  var port = 8888

  server.listen(port)

  console.log(`Server running and listening: http://localhost:${port}/`);
```

I'm not sure what is going on... I tried comment the conditional statments to see if I'd can write the data but the server crashed:

```
_http_outgoing.js:661
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('first argument',
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received undefined
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:661:11)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:629:15)
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:Myfoder/root/path)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:257:13) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Comment: Did you check what that `data` is ?

Comment: console.log(data) logs undefined... should I replace url module for path module to bring the correct path?